# Access Denied - Windows service web API controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

As a continuation on from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107646/how-to-test-apicontroller`...in short....

Im working on an existing Windows Service project in VS 2013.

I've added a web API Controller class...I've called it SynchroniseFromAwsServiceController

Im trying to call it from a AWS lambda call but it is telling me I dont have access. So I need to test it locally to see if it is working to try and diagnose the issue.

```
     namespace Workflow
    {

        public class SynchroniseFromAwsServiceController: ApiController
        {
            //// POST api/<controller>
            [HttpPost]
            public string SapCall([FromBody]string xmlFile)
            {
                string responseMsg = "Failed Import User";

                if (!IsNewestVersionOfXMLFile(xmlFile))
                {
                    responseMsg = "Not latest version of file, update not performed";
                }
                else
                {
                    Business.PersonnelReplicate personnelReplicate = BusinessLogic.SynchronisePersonnel.BuildFromDataContractXml<Business.PersonnelReplicate>(xmlFile);
                    bool result = Service.Personnel.SynchroniseCache(personnelReplicate);

                    if (result)
                    {
                        responseMsg = "Success Import Sap Cache User";
                    }
                }

                return "{\"response\" : \" " + responseMsg + " \" , \"isNewActiveDirectoryUser\" : \" false \"}";
            }
    }
    }
```

Im using PostMan to test this. Im running the application in VS and entering `http://127.0.0.1/SynchronisePersonnelXmlFromAwsServiceController/SapEaiCall` in the POST field in the POSTMAN ui...it returns the following:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Failed to start monitoring changes to
>   'D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax' because access
>   is denied. Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to
>   start monitoring changes to
>   'D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax' because access
>   is denied.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80070005): Failed to start monitoring changes to &#39;D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax&#39;
> ```
>
> because access is denied.]
>          System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.AddFileMonitor(String file) +9929663
>          System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.StartMonitoringFileWithAssert(String file,
>   FileChangeEventHandler callback, String alias) +89
>          System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.StartMonitoringFile(String alias, FileChangeEventHandler callback) +331
>          System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.SetupChangesMonitor() +122
>          System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Init() +161
>          System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureInited() +80
>          System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.SetupFileChangeNotifications() +71
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +57
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +260
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to start monitoring changes to &#39;D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax&#39;
> ```
>
> because access is denied.]
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +62
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +435
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +33
>          System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +563
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to start monitoring changes to &#39;D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax&#39;
> ```
>
> because access is denied.]
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10085904
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> ```
> [HttpException]: Failed to start monitoring changes to &#39;D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax&#39;
> ```
>
> because access is denied.
>          at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.AddFileMonitor(String file)
>          at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.StartMonitoringFileWithAssert(String file,
>   FileChangeEventHandler callback, String alias)
>          at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.StartMonitoringFile(String alias, FileChangeEventHandler callback)
>          at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.SetupChangesMonitor()
>          at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Init()
>          at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureInited()
>          at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.SetupFileChangeNotifications()
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>       [HttpException]: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax'
>   because access is denied.
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
>          at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
>       [HttpException]: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax'
>   because access is denied.
>          at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>          at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>          at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)

does anyone have any idea or can point me in the right direction as to why I am getting returned `<title>Failed to start monitoring changes to 'D:\Development\Trunk\WebAppsMVC\Icon\Icon\global.asax' because access is denied.</title>`

**UPDATE**

Thanks to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889297/failed-to-start-monitoring-changes-on-global-asax-net-3-5-web-service-using-imp`

Ive removed read only from the folder and added Authenticated Users. Now when I run, it gives me a different error but still says access denied....Am I using the correct URL?  `http://127.0.0.1/SynchronisePersonnelXmlFromAwsServiceController/SapEaiCall`

anyway the new error is:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access is denied. Description: An
>   error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this
>   request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested
>   URL.
>
> Error message 401.2 Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.
>
> Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based
>   on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled
>   on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for
>   additional assistance.

```
any help would be much appreciated thank you
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to George Vovos for the reply I have moved http to above the method and changed the signature to include controller.

In postman I have also included the basic value tag for authorization.

Now when I run the VS application locally and try to connect through post man with `http://localhost/WebServices.Workflow/SynchroniseFromAwsServiceController/SapCall`

(WebServices.Workflow being the application name)

I get the following message:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost/WebServices.Workflow/SynchroniseFromAwsServiceController/SapEaiCall
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

I have tried turning off SSL...any other ideas?

**NEW UPDATE**
Following on from a post I found I restarted PostMan and ran the POST again, and now the message is returning a `There is a duplicate 'exceptionless' section defined` which is what I get the I try to run the application from visual studio. So atleast its a step in the right direction (I think)...I have wrote a new Q regarding this...

[config file flagging as duplicate Exceptionless package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143847/config-file-flagging-as-duplicate-exceptionless-package)

**NOTE** if someone is able to help me answer this continuation Q, I will award them the bounty from this Q. **NOTE**

Thank You for any replies

Comment: can I ask why the -1 and why the close? I dont know why I am getting access denied and I am asking for help isnt that the point?

Comment: John,Can you paste a working sample?HttpPost is only valid for methods.The name of your class doesn't end with 'Controller' ,Your request url should not contain the 'Controller' suffix. Other than that there shouldn't be any problems,follow the conventions and let us know if you still have problems

Comment: thanks for reply, please see update of post

Comment: Have you tried connecting to `http://localhost/WebServices.SapEai.Workflow/SynchroniseFromAwsService/SapEaiCall`?

Comment: Hey @JohnEphraimTugado Yes I have, apologizes for that I was chopping and changing the URL it should be http://localhost/WebServices.Workflow/SynchroniseFromAwsServiceController/SapCall

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same error when deploying my ASP.Net Web API recently on my machine. What I did wrong was that I had not enabled Application Development Features required for it. You also need to check if you have the following features enabled on your local machine: [image]

You can navigate to ControlPanel -> Programs -> Programs And Features -> Turn Windows Features on  or off, to check if these features are enabled or not.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for the reply but If you read my NEW UPDATE on my post I was able to resolve this initial issue by restarting postman, simple I know but it worked. I did however offer the bounty to anyone who could answerhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143847/config-file-flagging-as-duplicate-exceptionless-package

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Windows Integrated Authentication to IIS. Check if it is installed:

Start > Run > `inetmgr`
Click Authentication

[image]

If Windows Integrated is missing you will need to install it following these steps:

**On Client OS:**
Start > Run >`appwiz.cpl`
Click 'Turn Windows features on or off'
Scroll down to Internet Information Services and expand it
Expand World Wide Web Services
Expand Security
Check off the Authentication methods you need (Windows Integrated)

**On Server OS:**
Go to your server manager (start->Administrative tools-> Server Manager)
Expand Roles and Web Server (IIS)
Scroll down to Role Services, and click Add Role Services on the right
Enable all the types you need under the security section

Comment: thanks for the reply but windows authentication is enabled

Comment: Does the account used to run the App Pool have access to the website folder and its files such as global.asax? Also try this, right click on Anonymous Authentication and choose Edit from the context menu. Try running it as a specific IUSR account instead of Application pool identity (or vice-versa).

Comment: yes the account has access and also the specific IUSR is already being used. Please see my update of original post, no longer getting access denied now getting 'could not get any response' thank You