# config file flagging as duplicate Exceptionless package

Tags: c#, web-config, nuget-package

Not sure what happened my project but when I tried to run it I got the error message `Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies`

Eceptionless.MVC is not used or referenced anywhere in my project I cant even find any text with Exceptionless......

So I used Nuget Manager to install the exceptionless.MVC package.

Now I get the error

```
`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Config Error
There is a duplicate 'exceptionless' section defined `
```

The install of exceptionless.Mvc added the following to my web config

```
 <section name="exceptionless" type="Exceptionless.ExceptionlessSection, Exceptionless" />
 <exceptionless apiKey="API_KEY_HERE" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ExceptionlessModule" type="Exceptionless.Mvc.ExceptionlessModule, Exceptionless.Mvc" />
    </modules>
```

and the packages config was updated

```
  <package id="Exceptionless" version="4.2.1982" targetFramework="net45" />
```

That is the only ref to exceptionsless/exceptionlessMVC in my project.

I am at a loss to what its look for with mvc exceptionless or where the duplicate sections are??

any help pls?

Comment: Restart your IIS/DevelopmentServer/PC and try again,you should be able to update the config fie then

Comment: Hey George thanks for the reply. So I closed and opend VS and edited the config file removing the only ref of name="exceptionless"  (which was flagging as duplicate when I tried to run...even tho it was the only ref)...no when I run the program I get 'Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Have you checked machine.config?

Comment: You don't have a dupe "ExceptionlessModule" in any of these places??     <httpModules>
      <add type="here_maybe" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
            <add type="here_maybe" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="here_maybe" />
    </modules>

Comment: Otherwise it is in the GAC and you want to remove the <modules> part in<section name="exceptionless"....

Comment: Check your system-wide web.config and machine.config (assuming .NET4.0 and higher) here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config and here C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was to do with a duplicate web config file stored in the IIS. Renaming that web config allowed the original to take priority removing any duplicate issues with exceptionless.

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing the handler then adding it back in.  Here is a similar example:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

You may need to comment out this part too.

```
 <section name="exceptionless"....
```

Answer (score 0):

Web.config is inheriting from Web.config from parent application. Also there is machine-wide web.config and machine.config.

1) If you application is on IIS and there is a parent application, check web.config of parent application

2) Check your machine-wide web.config and machine.config.
Assuming you're on .NET 4.0 and higher they're here:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
(for x32 bit application pool)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
(for x64 bit application pool)